# How to re-pair controllers when XMBC is started via autopilot?

Tags: controllers, ouya

I set up my OUYA to automatically boot up into XBMC (actually SPMC, if it makes a difference), which worked fine for a while. But unfortunately without any modifications on my side, my controllers won't connect now, and trying to re-pair them doesn't seem to work either, probably due to the main menu not even showing up to start the pairing dialogue. So, how can I fix this? Is there e.g. a way to disable the autoboot via a PC?

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, you can plug in a USB keyboard to the OUYA and, at least with XBMC, use the cursor keys and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to exit it and enter the controller pairing screen. However, the issue of controllers not pairing when autobooting into something seems to be a general issue now, so you need to deactivate the auto booting (enter autopilot and press the <kbd>U</kbd> button)...